# Can we prevent (or at least steamline) certain tags of questions

Tags: feature-request

I see people in this stack create questions asking if something contains asbestos and the response is always the same. No one can tell if it doesn't contain asbestos over the internet.

The tag already says "Please note that questions about identifying asbestos cannot be answered on this site and are likely to be closed as off topic. Asbestos identification requires a lab test." but that does not prevent asking such questions.

This [related question](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1525/should-asbestos-identification-questions-be-off-topic) covers the need for them to be off-topic, which is fine, but I feel like there are certain questions that

- simply should be prevented from posting (to reduce noise) **OR**
- posted and automatically closed as off-topic **OR**
- posted with an automatic community answer populated based on tag used and ***maybe*** accepted and closed automatically.

Community review could re-open closed questions if they are incorrectly caught up in the rule for the latter two.

Is there a mechanism in the SE to allow any of these options?